# How to show git differences like when performing a git pull?

Tags: git

When one performs a `git pull`, git outputs lines like:

```
myproject/myfile.py    |   2 +-
myproject/otherfile.py |  24 -------------
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 myproject/oldfile.py
create mode 100644 myproject/newfile.py
```

Is there a command to display such a summary when **not** performing a `git pull` ?

Answer (score 5):

Digging through the man pages, I finally found an answer:

```
git diff --summary --stat
```

Actually, `--summary` is responsible for displaying this part:

```
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 26 deletions(-)
delete mode 100644 myproject/oldfile.py
create mode 100644 myproject/newfile.py
```

While `--stat` is responsible for:

```
myproject/myfile.py    |   2 +-
myproject/otherfile.py |  24 -------------
```

This command can also be aliased like so:

```
git config --global alias.df "diff --summary --stat"
```

So one can just call:

```
git df HEAD~1
```

To show a summarized difference between the current and previous commit.

Answer (score 2):

On a side note to this, you can do a git diff on remote branches as well.  So you can see the changes before pulling.

```
    git diff HEAD origin/master
```

This will do a git diff of the current local, and show any changes that will happen when you do a git pull.

To get just the summary and stat you would do this

```
    git diff HEAD origin/master --summary --stat
```

Hope this helps out some.